# What is ExampleUnitTest in android studio

Tags: android-studio

My boss asked me to delete Non usable files in my project and asked me to delete **ExampleUnitTest** and **ExampleInstrumentedTest** What are these files used for and will it gonna be a problem if I deleted them?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple response is : No, there is no problem if you delete this files.

You can evaluate your app's logic using local [unit tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests) when you need to run tests more quickly and don't need the fidelity and confidence associated with running tests on a real device. With this approach, you normally fulfill your dependency relationships using either Robolectric or a mocking framework, such as Mockito. Usually, the types of dependencies associated with your tests determine which tool you use:

If you have dependencies on the Android framework, particularly those that create complex interactions with the framework, it's better to include framework dependencies using Robolectric.

If your tests have minimal dependencies on the Android framework, or if the tests depend only on your own objects, it's fine to include mock dependencies using a mocking framework like Mockito.

Then [instrumented unit tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests) are tests that run on physical devices and emulators. Instrumented tests provide more fidelity than local unit tests, but they run much more slowly. Therefore, we recommend using instrumented unit tests only in cases where you must test against the behavior of a real device.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to configure Android Studio to not create those files? I hate it that I have to delete them every time.